# Get organization Job title in AD using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been searching everywhere, and have tried many different combinations, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the "Job title" from the organization part of AD.

Here are a few things that I have tried

```
get-aduser -Filter * -SearchBase "Bob.Barker" -Properties sAMAccountName,Title

Get-ADUser -identity "Bob.Barker" -Filter * -Properties title | group title -NoElement
```

Also, as a bonus question how would you set the job title.

Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: `get-aduser -Filter * -SearchBase "Bob.Barker" -Properties sAMAccountName,Title` should work OK. What is the output and what do you expect it to be?

Comment: The output should be Bob Barker's Job title. instead I am getting 
get-aduser : The supplied distinguishedName must belong to one of the following partition(s): 'DC=foobar, DC=ForestDNSZones, DC=lala,DC=local at line:1 char:1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, if the user's username is Bob.Barker then use this:

```
get-aduser -Filter {samAccountName -eq "Bob.Barker"}  -Properties sAMAccountName,Title
```

or if surname is *Barker*

```
get-aduser -Filter {sn -eq "Barker"}  -Properties sAMAccountName,Title
```

Answer (score 3):

(old thread I'm aware, I'm just happy I know the answer to some of these questions - hopefully help out the next guy/gal that needs this reference quickly)

These chunks of powershell are correct:

```
get-aduser -Filter {samAccountName -eq "Bob.Barker"}  -Properties sAMAccountName,Title
```

(looking up by SamAccountname, a little more accurate)

```
get-aduser -Filter {sn -eq "Barker"}  -Properties sAMAccountName,Title
```

(Looking up by surname/lastname, if you have a big AD you'll have a lot of results to go through)

The other question above was

> Also, as a bonus question how would you set the job title.

Here it is below:

```
Get-aduser -identity bob.barker | set-aduser -replace @{title="New Job Title"} -whatif
```

I like using the -whatif, just in case something goes terribly wrong and I make the CEO the janitor or something.

And here you commit it: Notice, you find the user first with get-aduser, then in the pipe |, you set-aduser with the new value between the @{} braces

```
Get-aduser -identity bob.barker | set-aduser -replace @{title="New Job Title"}
```

And here's a bonus answer. If you want to export a whole bunch of users with the same title who need a new title, export your search results into a CSV:

```
Get-Aduser -filter 'Title -like "Old Job Title"' -Properties * | select samaccountname | Export-csv "C:\some_path\change_these_titles_samaccountnames.csv"
```

The exported CSV will only have the SamAccountnames that match that job title you're looking for (in this case "Old Job Title").

Now, create a few $variables to store the new job title, the CSV to import, and the samaccountname, and a for-loop to look at the CSV File.

```
$Set_Title=Import-CSV "C:\some_path\change_these_titles_samaccountnames.csv"
$New_Title="New Title for everyone in CSV file"
    foreach ($User in $Set_Title) {
        $User.sAMAccountName
        Set-ADUser -Identity $User.sAMAccountName -Title $New_Title
}
```

you could even put a count variable outside the for-loop to show how many users were updated:

```
$total = ($Set_Title).count
$total
Write-Host "AD User Titles have been updated..."
```

Hope this helps the next person out!

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get all the information you need, like title related or organizational info

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {samAccountName -like "*bla*"} -Properties *
```

Comment: This can easily clutter the console. Put it in a variable and from that do a Get-Member with 'where' to search for properties of the user account.